# move emails and attachments to google drive using php script

Tags: php, gmail, google-drive-api

I have read gmail email using PHP(imap_open) and i have to move emails and attachemts to google drive using php.

Email body text and file name are saved with me in php variable.

```
//code to connect gmail and read email
 $hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}test';
 $username = 'email@gmail.com';
 $password = 'pass';

  /* try to connect */
  $inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password);

  /* grab emails */
  $emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
```

All I want is to move these emails to google drive using php.

Comment: what are you asking? what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using PHP to read the emails & load the attachments, then look into the google drive SDK in PHP.

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-php

This tells you how to communicate with google drive and put contents on it.

Comment: I have to register with it?

Comment: I don't want to first download attachment then upload.My question is how from gmail I will able to save attachments to google drive.@Latheesan Kanes

Comment: @ZigMandel Its important some time to read question carefully then just comparing code with link code.It is clearly written on API example that "The file must be in the same location as the source code you paste" and mine requriment is to move file without downloading it.Secondly above mention code is for connecting to gmail.

Comment: The code you showed is about reading an email not about using the drive api. Saving an email is no diffrerent from saving any other file so its not relevant that your code only deals with the email data. Thats why you have a -1.

Comment: Given link is broken ! Here is the working link https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/php